# Can the Laplacian be thought of as $ \nabla^{\dagger} \nabla $?

Tags: operators, differentiation

I'm trying to read Peskin and Schroder's book on Quantum Field Theory. I was trying to justify transitioning from one line to the next by using the self-adjoint property of the Laplacian, $ \Delta = \nabla \cdot \nabla $, which I had proved by using an un-insightful integration by parts trick. This got me thinking:

- The Laplacian is self-adjoint: $ \Delta^{\dagger} = \Delta $.
- The Laplacian is an operator dotted with itself.
- Is there a sense in which we can write $ \Delta = \nabla^{\dagger} \nabla $?

By this, I mean that each element of the vector-operator $ \nabla^{\dagger} $ is the dagger of the element of the vector-operator $ \nabla $. This would make the self-adjointess manifest: $ \left ( \nabla^{\dagger} \nabla \right )^{\dagger} = \left ( \nabla \right )^{\dagger} \left ( \nabla^{\dagger} \right )^{\dagger} = \nabla^{\dagger} \nabla $.
Is there a way to formalize this idea?

My first thought: Perhaps if we thought of $ \left | \psi \right \rangle $ as a vector of infinitely many components, and each element of the vector-operator $ \nabla $ as a matrix acting on the input $ \left | \psi \right \rangle $, then each element of $ \nabla^{\dagger} $ could be thought of as the adjoint of the matrix in the corresponding element of $ \nabla $.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea! The thing is that the gradient is anti-self-adjoint, that is, $\nabla^\dagger=-\nabla$, so your proposed operator is just minus the laplacian.

Comment: This could be of interest to you...see Bochner Laplacian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry

Comment: @TylerHG and on that Wikipedia article you even hear that "the connection Laplacian and Bochner Laplacian differ only by a sign", which is in agreement with what Javier was saying

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I wondered when posting. I think the vast majority of applications would be in Physics (like the circumstance I ran across, when a dirty integration by parts is replaced by a simple proof-by-inspection), so that's why I posted here. I'm very open to it being moved, though, if several people think it should be.

Comment: I do not understand the point. $\nabla$ is not an operator on (smooth) wavefunctions since it transforms a *scalar* field $\psi$ into a *vector* field  $\vec{\nabla}\psi$. Therefore the notion of adjoint operator does not apply differently from the case of the single partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Sure. I guess I'd never seen the Laplacian in one-dimension, which is really just the second derivative, written as $ - \partial_x^{\dagger} \partial_x $. My answer actually just deals with one dimension. I was sloppy in my use of "operator".

Comment: @ValterMoretti If you think of the Laplacian as just the sum of one-dimensional second derivatives, I guess all I was realizing is a more manifest way of expressing self-adjointness.

Comment: Then, in the one-dimensional case, what you write is evident: $-\Delta = \nabla^\dagger \nabla$ (on smooth functions) just applying the definition of the adjoint of an operator.

Comment: I cannot see the point again.

Comment: @ValterMoretti What do you mean by "just applying the definition of the adjoint of an operator"? How did you get $ - \Delta = \nabla^{\dagger} \nabla $ straight from the definition of adjoint?

Comment: On smooth rapidly decreasing functions  and sticking to the one-dimensional case, we have $\langle (-\nabla) \psi| \phi \rangle = \langle  \psi| \nabla \phi \rangle$ just using integration by parts. This identity says that  $\nabla^\dagger = - \nabla$ (dealing with the afore-mentioned class of functions). Therefore $-\Delta = -\nabla \nabla = \nabla^\dagger \nabla$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Okay. "just using integration by parts". That's what I was trying to avoid. I think I found a different way of thinking about it in my answer (in terms of the matrices).

Comment: @ValterMoretti I also think NeuroFuzzy's idea in the comment to my answer is a third way of thinking about it (in terms of momentum being Hermitian - a physical fact).

Comment: I do not understand why one should follow a cumbersome way when there exist a straight way! :)

Comment: OK maybe I understand your point now, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think my idea works with the negative sign proposed by Javier.
Let's work in one dimension, so the gradient operator is really just a one-element ket containing the derivative operator. Let's write:

\begin{align}
\left | \psi \right \rangle & = \begin{pmatrix} ... \\ \psi \left ( -2 \epsilon \right ) \\ \psi \left ( - \epsilon \right ) \\ \psi \left ( 0 \right ) \\ \psi \left ( \epsilon \right ) \\ \psi \left ( 2 \epsilon \right ) \\ ... 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Where $ \epsilon $ is very small. We can now write:

\begin{align}
\partial_x & = \frac{1}{2 \epsilon} \begin{pmatrix} ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... \\ ... & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & ... \\ ... & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & ... \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \end{pmatrix} \\
\partial_x^{\dagger} & = \frac{1}{2 \epsilon} \begin{pmatrix} ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & ... \\ ... & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \end{pmatrix} \\
\Delta_{\text{proposed}} & = - \partial_x^{\dagger} \partial_x \\
& = \frac{1}{4 \epsilon^2} \begin{pmatrix} ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ ... & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 0 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 1 & ... \\ ... & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & ... \\ ... & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & ... \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Which is indeed the [second derivative limit formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210264/second-derivative-formula-derivation) (this exact matrix product doesn't work out near the boundary, hence the $ ... $'s).
In more than one dimension, we can treat it as a sum of one-dimensional derivatives, and for each such one-dimensional derivative we can pretend we are working in the above case. Therefore, I think we do have $ \Delta = - \nabla^{\dagger} \nabla $ in a fairly formal sense.

P.S. I guess it also checks out that $ - \Delta $ is a positive definite operator, while eigenvalues of most operators in quantum mechanics of the form $ A^{\dagger} A $ can be thought of as positive real quantities (the number operator, for instance).

Comment: Yep! Alternately, the fact that $\hat{p}=-i\hbar\nabla$ is self adjoint implies $-i\hbar\nabla=i\hbar\nabla^\dagger$, or $\nabla=-\nabla^\dagger$. (Really the implication goes the other way, I think, but it shows consistency at least)

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy I actually think that could suffice for a proof, if you use properties of physical reality as mathematical fact. We know measured values of momentum are real, therefore $ \hat{p} $ is Hermitian, and the proof follows. Nice insight!

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhat well-known as the generalization of the Laplacian as the [Laplace-deRham operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Laplace.E2.80.93de_Rham_operator). Given the exterior differential $\mathrm{d}$ (your $\nabla$, but acting to produce forms, not vectors) and its adjoint, the [codifferential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#The_codifferential) $\delta$ or $\mathrm{d}^\dagger$, the general Laplacian acting on a form is
$$ \Delta = \mathrm{d}^\dagger \mathrm{d} + \mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^\dagger$$
and when acting on an ordinary function the latter term vanishes, meaning $\Delta f = \mathrm{d}^\dagger\mathrm{d} f$.

Answer (score 1):

A third idea (the first and second being integration by parts and infinite matrices) is inspired by NeuroFuzzy's comment to my first answer (with matrices). Again in one dimension, we have $ \hat{p} = -i \hbar \nabla $, where $ \hat{p} $ is Hermitian because momentum must be real (in other words, $ \hat{p} $ is an observable). This tells us that:

\begin{align}
\left ( \hat{p} \right )^{\dagger} = i \hbar \nabla^{\dagger} & = \hat{p} = -i \hbar \nabla \\
\nabla^{\dagger} & = - \nabla
\end{align}

From which it follows that (again in one dimension) $ \Delta = \nabla^2 = - \nabla^{\dagger} \nabla $, again with the negative sign suggested by Javier. The extension to higher dimensions is then natural.